# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D:\wamp64\www\blog\modal\CommentManager.php on line 40

Tags: php

```
$bdd=$this->dbConnect();
$comment=$bdd->prepare('UPDATE commentaires SET commentaire=? WHERE id=? ');
$comment->execute(array($comment,$idComment));
$comment->fetch();
return $comment;
```

The update does not work: this code gives me an error in `execute()`:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in D:\wamp64\www\blog\modal\CommentManager.php on line 40

Comment: You want to return `$comment->fetch()`, not `$comment`

Answer (score 2):

You use `$comment` as variable for `PDOStatement` and again as value for the first input parameter.

Change `(array($comment, $idComment)` to `(array($textComment, $idComment)`:

```
<?php
$bdd = $this->dbConnect();
$comment = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE commentaires SET commentaire=? WHERE id=? ');
$comment->execute(array($textComment, $idComment));
$comment->fetch();
return $comment;
?>
```

Comment: thank you Zhorov you are right , i didn't pay attention of this detail